# create relations between multiple values nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

create a relationship between nodes with the property `input` and `output` where the output value of a node becomes input value to another node. 
for example i have 4 nodes, each node has property:

1. input: [y], output: [a, b]
2. input: [a], output: [c]
3. input: [b], output: [d]
4. input: [c, d] output: [x]

this is my cypher code :

```
MATCH (n:node), (m:node)
WITH n.output as output, m.input as input
FOREACH (output in n |
       FOREACH (input in m |
               MATCH n, m
               WHERE output = input
               MERGE (n)-[:NEXT_TO]->(m)
       )
)
```

the output of the cypher code above should be the relation `NEXT_TO` from node `1` to nodes `2` and `3`, relation `NEXT_TO` from node `2` to node `4` and relation `NEXT_TO` from node `3` to node `4`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
MATCH (n:node)
UNWIND n.output as output
MATCH (m:node) WHERE output IN m.input
MERGE (n)-[:NEXT_TO]->(m)
```